# Trouble with segue/unsegue when making a list app

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, segue, plist

I'm new to coding, so please bear with me.  I was following an online tutorial that worked with plists to make a habit list app.  I have a table view controller that shows a list of habits and a segue that presents modally a view controller that has text fields to add a habit.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvQOq.png)
Every time it runs, nothing happens when I click on the "save" and "cancel" buttons.  I realize this is a vague question as it doesn't pinpoint to a specific issue, but I am really struggling with fixing this issue and would really appreciate if someone proofreads the code.  The app builds and runs with no warnings.

This is the table view controller that shows the habits:

```
 class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

//MARK: Properties

var habits = [Habit]()

//MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return habits.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // Table view cells are reused and should be dequeued using a cell identifier.

    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") else {
        fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of ViewController.")
    }


    // Fetches the appropriate habit for the data source layout.
    let habit = habits[indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.text = habit.mainGoal
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = habit.microGoal

    return cell
}

@IBAction func unwindToHabitList(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    if let source = sender.source as?ViewController, let habit = source.habit {

        //add a new habit

        let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: habits.count, section: 0)
        habits.append(habit)
        tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: .automatic)
    }
}
```

This is the view controller that adds a habit:

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var saveButton: UIBarButtonItem!
@IBOutlet weak var mainGoalTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var microGoalTextField: UITextField!


var habit: Habit?

//method for configuring controller before presenting

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)
//configure this destination view controller only when save button is pressed
guard let button = sender as? UIBarButtonItem, button === saveButton else {
        os_log("save button was not pressed, cancelling", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
        return
    }

let mainGoal = mainGoalTextField.text ?? ""
let microGoal = microGoalTextField.text ?? ""

//set the habit to be passed on to tableViewController after the unwind segue
habit = Habit(mainGoal: mainGoal, microGoal: microGoal)
}


@IBAction func cancel(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    // Depending on style of presentation (modal or push presentation), this view controller needs to be dismissed in two different ways.
    let isPresentingInAddHabitMode = presentingViewController is UINavigationController

    if isPresentingInAddHabitMode {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else if let owningNavigationController = navigationController{
        owningNavigationController.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
    else {
        fatalError("The ViewController is not inside a navigation controller.")
    }
}
```

I appreciate any and all help in advance!

STORYBOARD CONNECTIONS:

[TABLEVIEW CONTROLLER CONNECTIONS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7CUE.png)
[ADD HABIT VIEW CONTROLLER CONNECTIONS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mt3d.png)

Comment: @NRitH I tried it out, and it didn't work.  I kept the import UIKit and os log at the top because that was necessary to build, but not sure what else I could do

Comment: Sorry about that--it wasn't a joke. You're right; you do have to include those imports, but for the purposes of *posting a question on Stack Overflow*, you don't have to post *complete* source files--posting only the relevant functions, properties, etc. should be enough.

Comment: Did you set up the proper storyboard actions for the `UIButton`s and outlets for the `UITextField`s?

Comment: @NRitH The Save button is linked to an action for the unsegue and is in the code but the cancel button is only linked to the code... Would I have to set up another segue from the cancel button to the tableviewcontroller?  I think you are right; I probably did not set it up right on the storyboard.  The textfields are set up in the code but I did not do anything within the storyboard. Do I have to?

Comment: So I connected the text fields to outlets- delegate as that's what makes most sense (I think?).  Not sure what to click on for the UIButtons

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of each view controller's Connections inspector?

Comment: Your first view controller should have an *action* connection from the `+` button to the view controller's function for adding a `Habit`, and a *segue* connection from the table cell to the navigation controller.

Comment: The Add view controller should have *outlet* connections from the view controller to the two text fields. The Save button should have a *segue* connection to the view controller's *exit* icon, from which you'd select the appropriate unwind segue name (`unwindToHabitList`). The Cancel button should be connected to the `cancel` *action*. Does that make sense?

Comment: Note that you don't need to call `super.prepare(for: segue, sender: any)`.

Comment: @NRitH I added screenshots of the connections in the post at the very end.  I'm pretty sure they're set up as you said, but it's still not working.